# What is the reason for using lowercase for the first word in a local variable (eg, employeeCount, firstName)

Tags: variables, methods, naming-standards

I take a good deal of criticism from other programmers due to my use of full proper casing for all my variables.  For example, your typical programmer will use `employeeCount` for a variable name, but I use `EmployeeCount`.  I use full proper casing for *everything*, be it a void method, return method, variable, property, or constant.  I even follow this convention in Javascript.  That last one *really* rustles people's jimmies.

The typical reason given as to why I shouldn't follow this "non-standard" casing convention is because full proper case should be reserved for properties and void methods.  Local variable and methods that return a value should have the first word in lowercase like `int employeeCount = getEmployeeCount()`.

However, I don't understand why.

When I question this, it seems that I just get an arbitrary answer of *that's the standard*.  Whatever the answer is, it usually always boils down to *That's just the way it is and I don't question it.  I just follow it.*.  Arbitrary answers are never good enough for me.

Ever since my early days of programming Excel 97 macros with the Office IDE, I've never needed a casing convention to tell me whether or not something is a local variable or property.  This is because I've always used a very intuitive naming convention.  For example, `GetNuggetCount()` clearly suggests a method that goes somewhere an gets a count of all the nuggets.  `SetNuggetCount(x)` suggests that you are assigning a new value to the count of nuggets.  `NuggetCount` all by itself suggests a property or local variable that is simply holding a value.  To that last one, one may be tempted to say, "Ah ha!  That is the question.  Property or variable?  WHICH IS IT?"  To that, I'd reply with, "Does it really matter?"

So here's the tl;dr;:  What are the objective, logical, non-arbitrary reasons to use lowercase for the first word in your variable or return method?

**Edit:**  For MainMa

Replace *this* code with the first code sample in your answer and see how well your argument holds up:

```
public void ComputeMetrics()
{
    const int MaxSnapshots = 20;

    var Snapshots = this.LiveMeasurements.IsEnabled ?
        this.GrabSnapshots(MaxSnapshots, this.cache) :
        this.LoadFromMemoryStorage();

    if (!Snapshots.Any())
    {
        this.Report(LogMessage.SnapshotsAreEmpty);
        return;
    }

    var MeasurementCount = Measurements.Count();
    this.Chart.Initialize((count + 1) * 2);

    foreach (var s in Snapshots)
    {
        this.Chart.AppendSnapshot(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, Erlang requires that variable names begin with an uppercase letter to differentiate them from [atoms](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id68597), which begin with a lowercase letter.

Comment: If they were in upper-case there would be someone else asking why aren't they in lower-case...

Comment: wouldn't it be nice if our all-powerful IDE's could have a plugin that mapped our own personal preferences for stylistic issues like this and allowed us to use them but behind the scenes, for the "real version" of the source file, applied the "project's" style semantics.  It is entirely a visual issue until you need to audit the official file version.  just dreaming...

Comment: @KenK That would be nice.  I know there are tools that will forcibly apply some standard formatting on checkin (whitespace, newlines, etc); but don't know of anything to switch to your style on checkout and for historical versions (for diffs).

Comment: Unfortunately for you, the actual and valid reason is "because it's the standard". It pays for people in the same team to follow the same code style standard. If you fail to see why, then maybe you should ask another question: "why are standards useful?"

Comment: If you want to be a rebel, then pick a different enemy: CamelCase itself! You can really tell the CamelCase pushers to go stuff it if you write your code nicely like this: `public void compute_metrics() { const int max_snapshots = 20; ... }`.

Comment: I've always assumed that developers settled upon camelCase because it looked kewl.  There's no 'objective' reason for camelCase *itself* above PascalCase.  I personally find PascalCase (like your example) to be much easier to read, and use it in most places other than JavaScript, where I keep with camelCase so I wont miss out on party invitations.

Comment: [Research into Advantages of Having a Standard Coding Style](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1325374/391656) It doesn't really matter what the standard is, just that it is followed.

Comment: There is a real reason to use lowercase/upper case in the programming language "Go": all variables and functions starting with a lower case are private to the current package, all others (starting with an upper case letter) are visible to the outside, and thus public.

Comment: Python answer: [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) exists. Use it.

Comment: Remember that you are not the only person in the world who will ever read your code. So don't code just four yourself. That's why naming conventions exist.

Comment: In Ruby, variables that begin with an uppercase letter are constants...

Comment: @Mr.Mindor, I've been at odds with that concept for over 40 years now.  Coding styles are wars that people seem to have religious views about, and I've never seen it help or hurt anything to have intermixed styling.  As in *never*.  I'll go further and say that anyone saying otherwise is merely looking for such problems.  I've seen code with Allman and K&R intermixed, for instance, and varying indents.  {shrug}  Capitalization is a slightly more poignant issue, but certainly nothing that truly matters.  Intermix away.

Answer (score 94):

That naming convention is often used when people want to be able to give a variable the same name as its type.  For example:

```
Employee employee;
```

Some languages even enforce that capitalization.  This prevents having to use annoying variable names like `MyEmployee`, `CurrentEmployee`, `EmployeeVar`, etc.  You can always tell if something is a type or a variable, just from the capitalization.  That prevents confusion in situations like:

```
employee.function(); // instance method
Employee.function(); // static method
```

Also, in English, nouns are not generally capitalized, so you can't really claim your capitalization is "proper."

So what does that have to do with your situation?  You obviously have no trouble reading your own code, but by keeping things as consistent as possible, you reduce the mental workload of anyone else needing to read your code.  In coding as in writing, you adjust your style to match the readers.

Comment: Note that the problem still exists in the language used by the OP, since properties are capitalized (of course, properties can be prefixed by `this.`, which avoids the confusion; local variables can't have such prefix).

Comment: Karl: In .NET, you can say `Employee Employee` and VS manages the scope perfectly.  In .NET, you cannot have an instance method and static method in the same class with the same name and signature.  Lastly, semantics on the word "proper". What should I use in its place? I can't say "uppercase" because that suggests the entire name is uppercase. How about `full camel`?

@MainMa: In .NET, I do this all the time: class x { int i { publix x(i) { this.i = i; } } }. Not sure if that's what you were addressing or not.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin it is called PascalCase.

Comment: `Employee Employee` works, but I'll argue that it is more confusing to a human reader than `Employee employee`. The latter looks like two different things. The first looks like needless repetition.

Comment: @JamieF: I'll argue that `Employee Employee` looks more consistent.  This, of course, assumes that the reader understands the underlying framework of the language they're using.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin Exactly: "assumes that the reader understands the underlying framework..." I like to read JavaScript, Java, C#, C++, and others and translate the code in my head. I don't like needing to keep thinking "Oh, this language's compiler can deal with _x_." while I'm just trying to get the meaning of the code.

Comment: Most of java/.net my code these days outputs some JSON. So I like to ensure my server side code naming standards match my JavaScript standards. So my list of objects in c# names will go directly into JavaScript. Using this standard keeps it consistant betweet languages as most JS I see uses lowercase for variables.

Comment: Note that `employee.function()` could also be a static method, if the language allows calling static methods from an object (like Java does). The compiler gives a warning, but it is allowed to do that.

Comment: "Also, in English, nouns are not generally capitalized, so you can't really claim your capitalization is "proper." Actually, proper nouns are capitalized and common nouns are not capitalized: "Boston is a city", "Canada is a country". Here "city" and "country" are types, "Boston" and "Canada" are variables. So I don't get why many conventions do other way around, like yours "Employee employee;". It looks unnatural like "boston is a City", "canada is a Country". I wonder if there is a good reason to make such unnatural conventions. P.S. English verbs are not capitalized as well

Answer (score 36):

There isn't any.  It is what most people do, so it has become the standard because that is what everyone does.  A lot of literature follows this convention so people picked up the habit.

The convention isn't as important as the consistency across the code.  As long as everything is named in a consistent manner so that I can tell what things are from looking at them, it doesn't really matter whether or not the first letter is capitalized or not.

I would find it jarring to come across code written in your manner and would say that I don't like it.  But that is a matter of style.

Now if you are doing this in the workplace, it would be better to code in the style of the team so that the code remains consistent everywhere.  Rather than having your code be different than everyone elses.

http://thecodelesscode.com/case/94

Comment: I wish most programmers were like you.  Many are questionably passionate and/or dogmatic about following the casing standard that I've mentioned.

Comment: @Schieis it matters if you are the next programmer to work on the project.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin You might end up being as passionate and/or dogmatic once you've worked on code that's full of `var m_someVariableID = GetVariableValueId()`. Especially if you have to do it *without* autocompletion support.

Comment: @N4TKD if the entire project was written in that manner, I could get used to it (I wouldn't like it necessarily).  I updated my question in regards to working with other devs.  The OP was also asking for a reason that the standard is the way it is.

Comment: If you are on a team, following that teams standard is important.  Note, however, that many programming languages have de facto standards which you should try to follow, when creating a new project where the team has no standards (or where the team has deferred to you to set them).  If you aren't sure what coding convention to use, following the convention used by either the primary language vendor or the included framework is preferable to your own standard, unless you can justify your standard.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin:  A lot of peoples' dogma eventually gets run over by someone else's karma.

Comment: @Schleis good update, I do not agree it is just a matter of style, but convention and convention becomes convention for good reasons and should be followed. Its not a religion and some time you must very from convention, but you should have a good reason.

Comment: I was going to +1, but that Codeless Code reference negated it.  Acting like an insane person != following coding conventions.

Comment: Only to note, that convention is language-wide and the code should be consistent with source of the libraries you use as well

Comment: How you achieve "consistency across the code" without a naming conventions beats me. Do you achieve it by coincidence ?

Comment: @user61852 There is a naming convention.  The OP has a convention where everything starts with a capital letter.

Comment: @Schleis A single user does not a convention make. A convention is something agreed upon by many people. Dictionary: "General agreement on or acceptance of certain practices or attitudes"

Answer (score 26):

### 1. Why the standard exists?

After all, wouldn't it be better to let everyone write the code according to personal preference, and stop talking about which standard is better?

The fact is that when you're habituated to one style, it is more difficult to read code which uses a different style. Your brain spends more time trying to understand the convention (if there is any), instead of understanding what the code does.

What is more readable between those two pieces of code?

```
public void comp_metrics ()
{
  int Count;
  List<snapshot> measurements=fromMemoryStorage();
  if (_liveMeasurements.enabled)
    measurements = GrabSnapshots(20, _cache);
    if( !measurements.Any() ) {
        this.Report(LogMessage.Measurements_Are_Empty); return;
    }

    Count = measurements.Count ();

    this.Chart.initialize(( Count + 1 )*2);

    foreach(snapshot S in measurements) {
      this.Chart.append_Snapshot ( S );
    }
}
```

or:

```
public void ComputeMetrics()
{
    const int MaxSnapshots = 20;

    var snapshots = this.liveMeasurements.isEnabled ?
        this.GrabSnapshots(MaxSnapshots, this.cache) :
        this.LoadFromMemoryStorage();

    if (!snapshots.Any())
    {
        this.Report(LogMessage.SnapshotsAreEmpty);
        return;
    }

    var count = measurements.Count();
    this.Chart.Initialize((count + 1) * 2);

    foreach (var s in snapshots)
    {
        this.Chart.AppendSnapshot(s);
    }
}
```

Both pieces of code execute similarly. The only difference is that in the first case, each developer who worked on the project used his own style. This made the code inconsistent, unreadable and hazardous. The fact that members of the team were unable to agree about the indent size, coupled with the fact that one of them was refusing to use curly braces after every `if` made the code extremely error prone: looking at it, we may believe that the second `if` is executed only when the first `if` is true, which is not the case.

In the second case, all developers followed the same standard. Some of them were maybe unhappy, because they preferred two spaces indentation or because they were used to methods which start with a small letter. The fact is that the code is still much more readable this way, and still would be if they were using any different standard.

By having a strict, uniform standard, it makes the code easier to read.

### 2. Why *their* standard is better than the one *I* invented right now?

If a standard is used by hundreds of thousands of developers around the world, just stick with it. Don't invent your own: even if it's better, it's easier for you to migrate to the global standard rather than to those hundreds of thousands of developers to start using yours.

Example: in my own company, I have a specific convention for naming primary and foreign keys and indexes in the database. Those names look like:

- `[FK for Application: CreatedByApplicationId]`,
- `[IX for SessionIPAddress: SessionId]` or
- `[PK for RoleOfPassword: RoleId, PasswordId]`.

Personally, I find this convention excellent and extremely clear. For me. But it totally sucks. **It sucks, because it's mine, and because no one of thousands of database administrators never used it.** This means that:

- When I will hire a DBA, he will be forced to learn the new convention, instead of starting his work right now,
- I can't share pieces of code on the internet as is: those strangely looking names will disrupt people who will read my code,
- If I take code from the outside in order to use it in my own, I would be forced to modify the names in order to make it uniform,
- If one day I decide to use some well-known standard, I will be forced to go and modify every of the few hundred names.

### 3. So, what about capitalization?

Properties have a larger scope or visibility than fields or local variables. Making properties start with a capital letter, and fields and variables - with a small one goes in this direction.

If you consider C#, this logic is consistent enough.

If you consider Java, methods start with small letters, which doesn't follow the logic.

So no, there is no definitive proof that this convention is better then yours. It's just that the one is used globally, and yours is not. None is *better*.

In JavaScript, functions start with a small letter, unless they require a `new` before them. Wouldn't it better the other way? Maybe. The fact is that for years, JavaScript developers used this standard, and not the opposite. Rewrite every book and force every developer to change the style now would be slightly complicated.

Comment: As for the part about code being less readable because it follows a slightly different standard, I've never had that problem.  Unless someone's variables are named like `hookyDookyDoo`, no naming or casing convention detracts from the readability.  Also, do keep in mind that I am not saying my convention is "better" since it doesn't truly bring anything special to the dev table.  Lastly, I don't understand your point of *[Properties have a larger scope...goes in this direction]*.  What does the scope have to do with casing convention?  Go in what direction?

Comment: @oscilatingcretin, the question isn't whether *you've* ever had that problem, it's whether your *colleagues* have.  Obviously they have, or they wouldn't be complaining.

Comment: Re: your edit:  Your first code example demonstrates simply poorly constructed, disaster-prone code.  My OP is not about poorly constructed, disaster-prone code.  It is about the exact same code as your second example, but different casing convention.  I edited your second code example and posted it in my OP with my casing convention.  Replace that with your first code example, please.

Comment: hmm, well I've certainly seen plenty of examples of that kinda code in real world production apps...

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: The first code example demonstrates not poorly constructed code, but code written by a team where every developer followed his own style. This happens with too many codebases, given enough time (for example five years). Note: have you missed the: *"The fact is that the code is still much more readable this way, and still would be if they were using any different standard."*?

Comment: @oscilatingcretin There's plenty of research that shows consistency significantly decreases the cognitive effort required to understand something you're reading. For regular prose, bad spelling, poor punctuation and lousy grammar all make it harder for someone to read - whether they notice it consciously or not. Code is hard enough to read, without making it harder - adherence to the "common standard" (for your technology stack of choice) increases overall consistency, and frees up neurons to concentrate on the important business of what the code does, instead of how it is written.

Comment: -1 for skirting the issue and answering a different, only tangentially-related question

Comment: +1 for hitting the issue and answering the *real* question, which goes beyond case use.  And for clear demonstrations of the impact of the problem.

Answer (score 11):

Technically, it doesn't matter (or at least, in most languages it doesn't).

However, most programming communities (whether those are world-wide communities that have formed around one particular language, sub-groups of such communities, groups that have formed around some popular library or toolkit, or just individual teams) have developed established coding standards. The exact details are relatively unimportant (though in many cases, a good argument can be made for them), what *is* important is that you stick to them.

Not because they're the best, but because they are what everyone else uses; if you stick with the standard, your code will be consistent with most of the other code that you will eventually end up using - libraries, teammates' code, language built-ins. Consistent naming is one powerful productivity weapon, because it means that when you guess the name of something, you will usually guess right. Is it `file.SaveTo()`, `File.saveTo()`, `file.save_to()`, `FILE.save_to()`? The naming convention will tell you.

Carrying your personal preferences into every language you encounter is particularly hazardous, because first of all, every language has its own culture, and the naming conventions are often incompatible; and second, there are many subtle differences between languages as far as naming is concerned.

Just one example: in C#, types and variables live in separate namespaces; the compiler is smart enough to know the difference. In C, however, both kinds of names share a namespace, so you can't have a type and a variable of the same name within the same scope. Because of this, C needs a naming convention that distinguishes types from variables, while C# doesn't.

Comment: So it really appears that some older languages have paved the road for coding standards of future languages (like your C/C# example).  That is most unfortunate because having to keep track of how to case variables and object members just adds an unnecessary level of complexity that can be done without.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin When everyone uses the same convention, it does not add ongoing complexity, the convention becomes part of your mental model for the language in question AND eases the use of that language. This is demonstrable and measurable.

Comment: I was going to vote you up but you first say that it doesn't matter then you write several paragraphs explaining why it does matter. If you delete the "it doesn't matter" at the beginning I'll vote you up.

Answer (score 11):

I'm surprised no one else has said this, but I think the capitalization difference is amazingly helpful for one reason: it's nice and convenient to be able to know whether a variable is only locally scoped or not. If the variable is local than I don't worry as much about side effects of changing it, such as refactoring the name. So I like a convention that distinguishes class members versus private class variables versus local variables.

With modern Intellisense, this matters less and less, but it still gives me some landmarks as I read code to know where I should look to find the definition.

And a fair bit of this may be left over from my worse style years ago, when methods weren't as likely to fit on one screen.

Comment: A number of projects that I've worked on specify something like this in their style guide.

Answer (score 7):

This seems more like a question of conventions rather than your specific convention.

For every convention you break, you're just adding more work for everyone else. Perhaps in a perfect world, the entire company works on a single product their entire lives... however, in reality, this is not true. People jump between projects, sometimes across companies or even for fun. The more random the code is, the harder and more expensive it is to work on. As a business owner or stakeholder, I wouldn't want to hire developers who think selfishly rather than for the good of the project.

This boils down to professionalism: sometimes we need to put our personal styles aside and go with what is more efficient for mass adoption. This encourages collaboration and removes extraneous barriers that shouldn't be there in the first place.

As for your actual convention, CapitalCamelCase is usually reserved for class names (or in Javascript, constructors). If I see a capitalized variable, an educated guess will dictate I'll need to instantiate it to use it. If that's wrong, I'm going to be pissed off that the code isn't following community standards. Even with most other languages, everybody else looking at it for the first time is instantly being misled. I want code to be obvious, not misleading.

Comment: "If I see a capitalized variable, an educated guess will dictate I'll need to instantiate it to use it."  I do not understand.  How would seeing a capitalized variable make you think you need to instantiate it before using it?  Because it looks like a class name?  So you don't know the difference between `MyClass MyClass = null` and `class MyClass { }`?

Comment: Yes, I see the difference. The convention exists to prevent ambiguity. `var car = new Car();` As per my last line - why not make it obvious?

Comment: @oscilatingcretin There is a difference, of course. But the human brain benefits from visual cues that a computer parser doesn't need. It seems as if you are questioning the need for conventions/standards... which is a valid, if different question than what you originally asked.

Answer (score 2):

"because full proper case should be reserved for properties and void methods. Local variable and methods that return a value should have the first word in lowercase" and becuase it is standard convention.

Other programmers are pulling up your code right now and thinking this is a property and it is really a local variable, your making their job harder.

Comment: Did you read my question in full?  Take a look toward the end where I said: `NuggetCount all by itself suggests a property or local variable that is simply holding a value. To that last one, one may be tempted to say, "Ah ha! That is the question. Property or variable? WHICH IS IT?" To that, I'd reply with, "Does it really matter?"`

Comment: Yes and Yes it matters, the next programmer should never need to think NuggetCount, you should be able to look at the name and tell. A good book to read is "Clean Code" you should be able to read the code like a story and know what is happening.

Comment: So what is your contention with NuggetCount as a variable or property name?  WHY does it matter?  What do you mean by *never need to think NuggetCount*?  Are you suggesting the naming convention (not casing convention) itself is flawed?  Give me some objective answers here.

Comment: In your case I have no idea what NuggetCount maybe, but because of convention I would think it is a property or a method that does not return a variable. Being it has the name NuggetCount I would think it is a property and I could get and/or set the NuggetCount from inside and outside the class. If it is a local variable I would hope it is private and I would be disappointed that I could not access it from outside the class, and I would have to rethink the changes or addition I was making to the class, and saying bad things about your ancestors :).

Comment: In my OP, I clearly talked about intuitive *naming* conventions (eg, GetNuggetCount() vs SetNuggetCount() vs plain ol' NuggetCount).  I've never met anyone who needs a casing convention to tell them what something is or how to properly use it.  So far, every bit of your contention here relates to 1) ambigous naming conventions, 2) improper use of access modifiers, and 3) inability to tell the difference between GetNuggetCount() and NuggetCount.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin I think the frustration you are seeing with people answering slightly different questions than you are asking is evidence of the confusion that can be generated when you break accepted conventions.

Comment: Conventions carry meaning. If according to convention NuggetCount implies a property, it means it has scope beyond what a local variable would have. Which means I have to research more to determine that scope. I need to determine: Are there side effects for changing it? Can I trust its value to not be changed by another thread while I am using it? nuggetCount implies local scope and I should be able to  assume its whole story is local.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor Or you can hover your mouse over the item in question and let your IDE tell you what it is.  With your method, you're trusting that the previous coder followed an established casing convention.  What if they didn't?  What if this property you speak of is actually named `nuggetCount`?  What do you do then?

Comment: @oscilatingcretin YES! Exactly! I trusted that what they wrote followed the convention and carried along all that goes with it. I trusted they were working as part of the team and I could reap the benefits of using that convention (knowing what nuggetCount was at a glance) If they did not, I probably do what your coworkers have done: I try to educate the one responsible, and I waste more time next time I have to follow them by not trusting. By not following the convention they have produced less readable, less maintainable code. Do you have a reason for wanting to buck the convention?

Comment: @oscilatingcretin It's difficult to hover your mouse on the printed out copy of the code, or the piece that was in the WTF email you sent a colleague.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said no real reason, except for getting a naming convention down pat. If you can get your whole team on the same page you can probably save yourself some time. For instance personally I started a coding standards thing which went into this and we used camelCase for all private varials as well as things passed byVal, whereas we used PascalCase for things that are public as well as things passed by Ref.

Lines get a little blurry when dealing with things like protected or Out or something.

Answer (score -2):

Language (with its formal aspect and conventional) is important for organizing your thoughts, it has power over your ways of thinking. So it just a pain to transit from one style to another.

Low case and upper case symbols have big semantic differences in Haskell, also they differs lightly in Scala and I've used both of them. Other languages I use make no difference between this two kinds of identifiers, but keeping thoughts in the way Haskell perceive identifiers just much easier for me than to fragment my mind for different languages.

Answer (score -2):

For me it comes down to expectation.

When I read most code, I expect anything that starts with a `lowerCase` to be a local variable or a function (in C# that would be just a variable).  If I see a local variable in `ProperCase`, I would likely stumble and get confused for a while, thinking that it's either a class name or a property or something else.  That would cause me to re-read the code, and would annoy me.

That is likely what's happening in your case.

Plus, it's convenient to be able to tell what role a variable plays just by looking at the first letter, and it avoids clashes between an instance name and a class name.

Answer (score -3):

Lower case should be used for local variables for ease of typing (speed / no shift key). Upper case is used to help readability by separating the words within a name. Code with single-word local variable names (which should be common) are fast and easy to type. The use of upper case for each new word in the name is also faster (and less space) than using underscores which add another character - this is also known as camel-case.

Comment: I think this is a very good answer and i don't understand the down-votes. It's a logical answer - based on facts as was requested by the OP. If you down-vote please explain yourself. The shift key pressing all over the place is massive. Think about it, almost every word you type in your code will start PascalCase and for each one you will need another shift key press. If you wanna be minimalist and effective makes sense to remove the unnecessary shift key presses. And logically speaking you would wanna be more productive, which from where i'm standing means pressing less keys. Why press more?

Answer (score -3):

I agree with the OP here. camelCase just looks wrong. I also agree with the fact that that is the standard and we must stick to the same standard or what is the point of having a standard. It also makes sense that PascalCaps be used for methods etc and camelCase for your own variables etc as a way of differentiating when not using an IDE that colors methods for you.

To get around it, I always prefix my object's names with the type of object it is. So if it is a string variable I call strMyVariable. If it is some sort of object I call it objMyObject, etc. That way it starts with small caps as per the standard and it looks right.

Comment: this doesn't seem to offer anything substantial over points made and explained in prior 11 answers